# No lights or power but starts off kick, has brand new battery still nothing

Tags: motorcycle, electronics, mechanics-trade

I have a pioneer xf125 has no power at all but runs off kickstart and the kill switch works other than that no light or anything, could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thank you hopefully someone may be able to help me

Comment: Have you checked the fuses? What other diagnostics have you done? Did you check any of the wiring going to the switch? How old is the bike? How many many miles?

Answer (score 0):

There are two red wires connected to the + terminal of the battery. One of them goes to the starter relay, the other goes to the rest of the electrical system. That second red wire has an inline fuse. Find that inline fuse and check it. Replace if necessary. If the fuse blows again, you have a short circuit somewhere.